# Troubleshooting inductor issues in an ultrasonic humidifier PCB

Tags: pcb-design

I'm developing a humidifier PCB module to power the fogger transducer for mist generation.

Components:

- 12V 2A VCC knput
- Bojack 220uH 1W inductor (inexpensive kit from Amazon)
- 16mm fogger transducer operating at 113kHz
- IRFZ44 TO-220 MOSFET
- NE555N oscillator
- Supporting resistors as per the schematic diagram below.

Upon powering up the PCB, the inductor heats up rapidly leading to the burning out. Unfortunately, I couldn't locate a datasheet for the inductor.

Why does it burn out? Is it because it cannot handle the current? Is there a stronger inductor that can handle higher currents that I could use? Is there an issue in the schematic diagram I'm not seeing?

[image]

Comment: Do you know the average current draw, and the DC resistance of the inductor? From this you can calculate the power disippation, and compare with the 1W rating.

Comment: R30 is way too large. When you are switching at a high frequency, you want roughly 100 ohms.

Comment: @colintd all I know is what is provided from Amazon description - 1W, tolerance: 10%

Comment: @Mattman944, thank you, does too large resistor may lead Mosfet not to close completely, which could cause the short circuit?

Comment: The MOSFET gate voltage probably looks like a triangle wave instead of a square wave. The MOSFET is probably getting very hot also. Note this circuit has two key differences from yours: gate resistor, cap in parallel with the transducer. https://www.electroschematics.com/ultrasonic-mist-maker/

Comment: Maybe use a free wheeling diode across inductor because the inductor doesn't want sudden change in current.

Comment: @Mattman944 you were absolutely correct, it was the R30. by switching to 100ohms transducer started to operate. Although I'm still slightly mystified about the parallel cap with transducer what is the role of it? Transducer stops operating once connected. If you would like so, please copy paste your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. This means world for me.

Comment: Go ahead and accept *qrk's* answer. I was too busy to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, the series gate resistor is much too large. The waveform presented at the gate (V(b)) is a triangle wave centered at about 6 volts which keeps the transistor on at all times, about 1A which is limited by the series resistance added to the inductor model in the SPICE simulation. 
The LTspice simulation shows this. The upper graph is with series gate resistor at 10k ohms, the lower graph is with the series gate resistor at 50 ohms. The transducer model is a very simple model and values are chosen to resonate the circuit at around 113 kHz. Depending on your transducer, you may need to add a capacitance across the transducer to properly resonate the circuit.

You also need to add some capacitance on the VCC power rails on the physical circuit, perhaps 100 nF and 100 uF.

An inductor with a specification of 1 W means nothing. Depending on the inductor construction, you could saturate the inductor which will cause problems.

[image]